# Content Query WP with Document Library

Tags: document-library, content-query-web-part

When created a CQWP to load a doc library of a subsite, it seems that the subfolders of the parent folder were also displayed. Is there any way to display in hierarchy like the subfolders are under the parent folder...

Or any better way to display a doc list in a subsite of the root site collection?

Comment: can you please be more specific with your question?means add some more details or some screen snaps,so viewrs will be more clear with that

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a List View Web Part to display the document library instead. This will allow you to manipulate the view of the library (which, to my understanding, is what you're looking for).

1. Open the document library in SharePoint Designer
2. Right-Click within the `<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>` tag and select "Tag Properties"
3. Click "OK" on the window that pops up. A new ribbon category should appear
4. Under "List View Tools" click "Web Part" and then on the far right, "To Site Gallery"
5. Click "Ok" on the first pop up window
6. Then make sure to hit "Yes" on the second pop up message

The new web part will be under "Miscellaneous." You add it and can manipulate the view just like a normal document library.

[Microsoft Info on List View Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/List-View-Web-Part-ced04ead-c6b5-4c43-a3f0-70c5408ef5a6)

Comment: this does not seem to work in Sharepoint Online. I tried this and I get List not found whenever I try to add the webpart

Comment: Make sure you follow step 2. If the ribbon shows `Code View Tools` and `Web Part Tools` then it will not work. The ribbon must show the `List view Tools` with Web Part as an option. The message that starts, "Do you want this Web Part to always show..." must pop up and you must hit "Yes" for the web part to work.